# No transactional EntityManager available Error

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-transactions

I have a below spring setup. Basically I am trying to configure two transaction managers here. One with hibernate and other with JPA. But somehow when I try to run JPA transaction manager, there I get **"javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No transactional EntityManager available"** error. Appreciate if somebody finds the problem in below code.

data-context.xml file as below

```
  <bean id="fundBO" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="proxyInterfaces" value="com.test.FundBo"/>
        <property name="interceptorNames">
            <list>
                <idref  bean="transactionInterceptor"/>
                <idref bean="fundBOTarget"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="fundBOTarget" class="com.test.FundBoImpl" />


<bean id="transactionInterceptor" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
    <property name="transactionManager">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And AppConfig as Below.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.**"})
@ImportResource("classpath:data-context.xml")
public class AppConfig { 

    @Resource
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        transactionManager.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        transactionManager.setNestedTransactionAllowed(true);
        transactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();
        return transactionManager;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.test.**");
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", "20");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.autoReconnect", "true");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.autoReconnectForPools", "true");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.is-connection-validation-required", "true");
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you need hibernate and jpa in two different transaction managers? _In addition to its own "native" API, Hibernate is also an implementation of the Java Persistence API (JPA) specification_

Comment: Hi Patrick, the xml configuration is used for batch job (Legacy code) where in JPA handles the online request from web page.